# How do I install Devel::REPL including `optional_features` from the distro meta file?

Tags: perl, perl-module

How do I install [`Devel::REPL`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel%3a%3aREPL) including [`optional_features`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel%3a%3aREPL#OPTIONAL-FEATURES) from the distro meta file?

Meta file: [`Devel-REPL-1.003025 / META.json`](https://metacpan.org/source/ETHER/Devel-REPL-1.003025/META.json)

Tried with `cpanm` and `cpan`.

`PERL_MM_USE_DEFAULT=1` does not help.

Comment: When all else fails, install the option features' modules manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `App::cpanminus` (`cpanm`) has a `--with-all-features` flag you can use.

For more details see: https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-cpanminus/bin/cpanm#with-feature---without-feature---with-all-features.

Note if you've installed the latest version of Devel::REPL already you may have to use the `--reinstall` flag as well.

```
~$ cpanm --reinstall --with-all-features Devel::REPL
```